# How to get "this" variable mixing php and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a set of boxes:

HTML

```
<button class="btn-modal">
   <div>Ajax content 1</div>
</button>
<button class="btn-modal">
   <div>Ajax content 1</div>
</button>
```

In the PHP loop I do:

```
<?php 
$permalink = get_permalink(); // Link of the box
?>
<script>
var simple = '<?php echo $permalink; ?>';
</script>
```

The php loop above prints the correct link for each box link in each `simple` variable

I then call the content via ajax like this:

```
$(document).on( 'click', ".btn-modal", function(){
  var cont = $(this).simple +  " .content"; // Load via ajax the Box link + content 
  jQuery(".modal-body").load(cont);
});
```

The variable `simple` is applied to all the boxes correctly but I am not getting `this box link on click` but I am getting a no found error instead

```
http://www.example.com/xchanges/home/work/interactive/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: That's not how variables work.  Use `data-*` attributes

Comment: You're using the link as a dynamic property of a jQuery object. It doesn't exist.

Comment: `simple` is not a property of a jQuery object. I don't understand what the connection between the variable `simple` and the rest of the code is.

Comment: but it is showing me the correct link as a string for each "simple" variable

Comment: `$(this).parent().simple +  " .content";` makes no sense.

Comment: .parent was just a typo as the code isn't this simple all together... updtaing the question

Comment: @rob.m: Still the same problem. `$(this)` is a jQuery object and jQuery objects don't have a `simple` property. `$(this).simple` is `undefined`, which would explain why you see `undefined` at the end of the URL.

Comment: `simple` has become way too simple!

Comment: I used to do `url = this.href + " .content"; where href was the a link but in this case I wanted to grab the box link
`

Comment: In that case you should do `jQuery(".modal-body").load(simple);`

Comment: @JFK I want to only grab the content within .content in the simple link

Comment: `The php loop above prints the correct link for each box`. What loop? I think you should post more of the program at this point I don't know how to answer. If you are redefining `simple` that would be a problem.

Comment: Then try `jQuery(".modal-body").load(simple + " #content")` (you may need to target the section's ID the same way you do `href="#content"` and not `href=".content"`)

Comment: @FelixKling that's correct but how do I get the simple variable of each box I printed in the pho loop so that i can use $(this) to target the correct variable ?

Comment: @JFK but I am wondering which simple is it? how will it know that I am saying THIS simple meaning the simple variable of this box where this button I am clicking is?

Comment: It's completely unclear what "`simple` variable of this box" means. JavaScript variables don't have *any* connection to an HTML/DOM element. Varian In order to use `$(this)` to get data from a DOM element, you actually have to associate data with the DOM elements, which you can do if you use `data-*` HTML attributes (as already mentioned earlier).

Comment: @FelixKling I see, so what you are suggesting is to print the simple as a data attribute so that I can access it with e.g. this.data ?

Comment: `$(this).data('whatever-the-name-is')`, yes.

Comment: In your context `$(this)` refers to the clicked button so you may need to add a `data` attribute in that button that indicates the selector (ID) you are targeting within `simple`

Comment: Then you could do something like `jQuery(".modal-body").load(simple + " #" + $(this).data("id"))` ... assuming you have a `data-id="something"` attribute in your clicked button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess i understand what you want to do. Your approach is not the correct way, you want to save a link for each div and then use that link in some JS logic.

Then in your loop (this is Wordpress right ?) you need to set out the link in the DOM element you want inside a `data-attr` and also give some class name to that div so that you can actually select it using JS

```
echo '<div class="someClass" data-src='. get_permalink() . '> .....
```

The result should be:

```
<div class="someClass" data-src="http://..." >Ajax content 1</div>
```

Now, your JS

```
$(document).on( 'click', ".btn-modal", function(){
  var cont = $(this).children('.someClass').attr('data-src') + " .content";
  jQuery(".modal-body").load(cont);
});
```

Comment: thanks man, I was working already on something very similar to yours as the users comments have suggested. I'll accept it to give you a buzz :)

Comment: great thanks ;) good luck and let me know if you have any other questions